# Google Sheets - move rows from one sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have Gooogle sheet where-in, I have two sheets named "Master_Software_Inventory" and "Retired_Inactive" which is like :

"Master_Software_Inventory" is like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxKmu.png)

"Retired_Inactive" is like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWfQo.png)

I would like to move all the rows from the sheet "Master_Software_Inventory" to the sheet "Retired_Inactive", when Status in "Master_Software_Inventory" becomes "Inactive".

However no rows are getting moved to the sheet "Retired_Inactive", when the when Status in "Master_Software_Inventory" becomes "Inactive".

I have already granted "Google Sheets API" access in Services, allowed the required access

I am testing with the below code

```
/*
function onOpen() { //Add a custom menu to the menu bar
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Admin')
      .addItem('Archive', 'archive')
      .addToUi();
}
*/


//NOTE!!!  IMPORTANT!!!
//For testing and debugging - Remove the slashes in front of the Logger.log() lines - run the
//code and then in the VIEW menu - VIEW the LOGS - Provide the LOG print out if there is an error

function archive() {
  var arrayOfRowsToArchive,columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor,data,i,lastColumn,L,numberOfRowsToArchive,numRows,
      range,rowsToDelete,ss,sheet,sheetName,sheetToMoveTheRowTo,startRow,status,targetSheet,thisRowsData,
      valuesToTestFor;

  //USER INPUT:
  
  startRow = 2; //The row number to start from where the data starts - exclude header rows
  valuesToTestFor = "Inactive";//Type one or more values to test for - If multiple values seperate by comma
  columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor = 0;
  sheetName = "Master_Software_Inventory";//Name of sheet tab where the data will be removed from
  sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Retired_Inactive";
  
  //END OF USER INPUT
  
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);//Get the sheet tab with the data to be searched
  
  numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

  arrayOfRowsToArchive = [];
  rowsToDelete = [];

  //The getRange() method uses parameters of (start Row, start Column, Number of Rows to get, Number of Columns to get)
  data = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - startRow, lastColumn).getValues();//Get all values except the header rows
  
  L = data.length;//Get the number of rows that are in the data
  
  for (i=0; i<L; i++) {//Loop through all the rows of data
    status = data[i][columnNumberOfValuesToTestFor];
    Logger.log('status: ' + status);
    
    if (valuesToTestFor.indexOf(status) !== -1) {//Search for a match between the cell value and values to look for
      thisRowsData = data[i];//Only get inner array of data
      //Logger.log('thisRowsData: ' + thisRowsData)
      arrayOfRowsToArchive.push(thisRowsData);//Push one row of data to outer array
      rowsToDelete.push(i+startRow);//Get the row number to delete later
    }
  }

  if (arrayOfRowsToArchive) {
    numberOfRowsToArchive = arrayOfRowsToArchive.length;
    
    if (!numberOfRowsToArchive) {
      return;//No rows were found to archive
    }
  } else {//There is no good value for arrayOfRowsToArchive- There was an error
  
    Logger.log('There is a problem with arrayOfRowsToArchive');
  }
  
  targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, numberOfRowsToArchive, arrayOfRowsToArchive[0].length)
    .setValues(arrayOfRowsToArchive);

  //Logger.log('rowsToDelete: ' + rowsToDelete)
  
  for (i=rowsToDelete.length;i>0;i--) {//Delete from bottom up
    Logger.log((i-1).toString())
    Logger.log('rowsToDelete[i-1]: ' + rowsToDelete[i-1])
    sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[i-1]);
  }
}
```

The execution logs just prints

> Execution log
> 4:23:21 PM    Notice  Execution started
> 4:23:21 PM    Info    status: 123
> 4:23:21 PM    Info    status: 456
> 4:23:21 PM    Info    status: 789
> 4:23:21 PM    Info    status: 987
> 4:23:22 PM    Notice  Execution completed

Any help to solve this is appreciated

Pasted my app_code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  var sr = e.source;
  var rw = rg.getRow();
  var vl = rg.getValue();
  var sh1 = sr.getSheetByName("Master_Software_Inventory");
  var sh2 = sr.getSheetByName("Retired_Inactive");
  if (rg.getColumn() == 6 && vl == "Inactive") {
    var data = sh1.getRange(rw, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    sh2.appendRow(data[0]);
    sh1.deleteRow(rw);
  }
}
```

This is an example of what it does:

[image]

If you'd like to run the function with a custom menu, you can use this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = sr.getSheetByName("Master_Software_Inventory");
  var sh2 = sr.getSheetByName("Retired_Inactive");
  var rg = sh1.getRange(1, 6, sh1.getLastRow(), 1);
  var vl = rg.getValues();
  for (var i = sh1.getLastRow() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var cF = vl[i][0];
    if (cF == "Inactive") {
      var dt = sh1.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      sh2.appendRow(dt[0]);
      sh1.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I get when I run the script:

[image]

##### EDIT:

If you would like to include the cell's text and fill color, change `var data = sh1.getRange(rw, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues();` to `var data = sh1.getRange(rw, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn());` and `sh2.appendRow(data[0]);` to `data.copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1));`. What the code would look like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  var sr = e.source;
  var rw = rg.getRow();
  var vl = rg.getValue();
  var sh1 = sr.getSheetByName("Master_Software_Inventory");
  var sh2 = sr.getSheetByName("Retired_Inactive");
  if (rg.getColumn() == 6 && vl == "Inactive") {
    var data = sh1.getRange(rw, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn());
    data.copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
    sh1.deleteRow(rw);
  }
}
```

This is what it does:

[image]

The same thing applies if you'd like to do this using a custom menu:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = sr.getSheetByName("Master_Software_Inventory");
  var sh2 = sr.getSheetByName("Retired_Inactive");
  var rg = sh1.getRange(1, 6, sh1.getLastRow(), 1);
  var vl = rg.getValues();

  for (var i = sh1.getLastRow() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var cF = vl[i][0];
    if (cF == "Inactive") {
      var dt = sh1.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, sh1.getLastColumn());
      dt.copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
      sh1.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .... The above code works, when the status is edited as Inactive, the row moves to the sheet "Retired_Inactive"

My current working sheet has all these values already, and I need to move them to the sheet "Retired_Inactive". 

Also, I would like to retain the ROW format like Cell Text Color and Fill Color

How can I do that ?

Comment: You may use the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) method instead of `sh2.appendRow(dt[0]);`. I'll edit my answer with an example output.

Comment: The above modified code works, thus moving the values to archive sheet with its row format intact

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function archive() {
  var archrows = [];
  const tstidx = 0;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Master_Software_Inventory");
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Retired_Inactive");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const tvalues = ["Inactive"];
  var d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~tvalues.indexOf(r[tstidx])) {
      archrows.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
  if (archrows.length > 0) {
    tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archrows.length, archrows[0].length).setValues(archrows);
  }
}
```

Comment: tried the code with its entire code being as above, still the results are nothing, no rows moved to second sheet

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Try setting a breakpoint at `if (archrows.length > 0)` and then run debug.  Make sure there are some rows columnA that are inacive.  Let know what your getting for vs and archrows

Comment: Make sure  your sheet names are correction and don't have any extra spaces in them